# Why string[0] = "new value" does not compile?

Tags: c#, .net

How I set new value for an string by index value?

I tried:

```
string a = "abc"; 
a[0] = "A";
```

not works for `strings`, but yes for `chars`. Why?

Comment: Besides strings being immutable, `a[0]` will return a `char` reference and you're trying to assign a string to it with the double quotes, so it should be single quotes. But it won't work even if you use single quotes :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Strings in C# (and other .NET languages which use `System.String` in the base class library) are immutable. That is, you can't modify a string character by character that way (or for that matter, can you modify a string ever).

If you want to modify a string based on the index, you have to convert it to an array using `System.String.ToCharArray()` first. You convert it back to a string using `System.String`'s constructor, passing in the modified array.

Your example would have to be changed to look like:

```
string a = "abc";
char[] array = a.ToCharArray();
array[0] = 'A'; //Note single quotes, not double quotes
a = new string(array);
```

Comment: StringBuilder is also useful for this purpose.

Comment: @supercat: I'm not familiar with that. Can you post it as another answer so that it can be upvoted?

Answer (score 5):

The `System.String` type does not permit writing by index (or via any means -- to change a the content of a `String` variable, one must replace it with a reference to an entirely new `String`). `The System.Text.StringBuilder` type does, however, permit writing by index.  One may create a new `System.Text.StringBuilder` object (optionally passing a string to the constructor), manipulate it, and then use its `ToString` method to convert it back to a string.

Comment: 1. +1. 2. Modified slightly. Please revert if you disagree.

Comment: @Billy ONeal: I reworded the parenthetical note further.  Tell me what you think.  I reverted the language about "its `ToString` method" because (1) it's an instance method, (2) the instance in question is the grammatical antecedent, and (3) the ToString function is actually a function on Object.

Answer (score 3):

A replacement would be this:

```
string a = "abc";
a = a.Remove(0, 1);
a = a.Insert(0, "A");
```

or for the C say:

```
string a = "abc";
a = a.Remove(2, 1);
a = a.Insert(2, "C");
```

Also using a stringbuilder may work as per http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe.aspx

```
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("abc");
 sb[0] = 'A';
 sb[2] = 'C';
 string str = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: Strings are immutable, so you'd need to write `a = a.Remove(...)`

Comment: No, you did not. `Remove` returns a copy of the string with those bits removed. It does not modify the string you call it on.

Comment: Removed my downvote. I still dislike this solution because it copies the string entirely too many times, but I don't dislike it to the point of downvoting.

Answer (score 2):

Use [StringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx) if you need a mutable String.
Also: a[0] can represent one character while "A" is a String object-it is illegal.

Answer (score 1):

a[0] for a character is a address in memory to which you can assign a value.

string on the other hand is a class and in this case the a[0] is actually a function call to the overloaded [operator](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator%5B%5D/)[]. You can't assign values to functions.

Comment: You can assign values to the result of the `[]` operator if that is defined to not be read only. (`System.String` does define it to be readonly, but e.g. `System.Collections.Generic.List` does not)